# How to convert date and time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have the following columns in a table:

```
Signed_In_Date             Signed_Out_Time
11/1/2005 12:00:00 am      11/1/2005 10:27:00PM
```

I would like to convert them to the following output:

```
Signed_In_Date      Signed_Out_Time
11/1/2005           10:27:00PM
```

Is there a function or conversion code in SQL Server that would do it?

Comment: Are you storing these dates as strings? If so, it would be much easier to convert these fields to datetime type if you're planning on doing manipulation to the dates. You should probably be doing that anyways.

Comment: What datatypes are those columns, what version of SQL Server are you using and what format date is that MM/dd or dd/MM?

Comment: Most probably, there _is_ a function. The exact answer may depend on a particular sql server.

Comment: I would like to see these as trings and actual dates. Also, I am using SQL server 05/08.

Comment: THen you need to learn to use  a database. strings are the wrong way to store them to start with.

Comment: In SQL Server **2008**, you could use `CAST(... AS DATE)` and `CAST(... AS TIME)` using the new `DATE` and `TIME` datatypes.

Comment: Hey @joe. Did any of these answers help you/fix your problem? Consider marking one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the columns you're referring to are `DATETIME` columns, I would use the code below:

**Date Only**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
```

**Time Only**

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))
```

You can see the queries in action / play with them [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64517/date-only-time-only).

Answer (score 2):

For Sign_In_Date Use

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'11/1/2005 10:27:00PM',108)
```

Ouput:

```
11/1/2005
```

For Sing_Out_Time

```
declare @time time
set @time=cast('11/1/2005 10:27:00PM' as Time)
select convert(varchar(10),@time,100)
```

Output:

```
10:27PM
```

Answer (score 1):

try that :

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Signed_Out_Time,108)  ,-- 108 is d/M/yyyy if you want mm/dd/yyy you should use 101
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Signed_In_Date,103)
```

Comment: You'll need more than 8 to store MM/DD/YYYY (or DD/MM/YYYY, who knows) - so use `VARCHAR(10)` atleast :)

Comment: @cairnz yeah i copy paste it should be 10 and 8. 11:11:11

Answer (score 1):

You can use CONVERT to change datetime format to your own desirable format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Signed_In_Date,101) as 'Signed_In_Date',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Signed_Out_Time,108) as 'Signed_Out_Time';
```

For more date format, go over this link:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx